# Multiple conditions if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, int

I am trying to build a few 'if statements' with clauses in. Basically if the rating is between 0 and 1 I want to show a picture, if its between 1 and 2, I show another picture etc.

Unfortunately I get the error from the compiler saying 'Expected expression'. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
if (self.rating => 0 && self.rating < 1) {//rating between 0 and 1
        self.finalRatingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ratingSS1.png"];
    }else if (self.rating >= 1 && self.rating < 2){
        self.finalRatingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ratingSS2.png"];
    }else if (self.rating >= 2 && self.rating <= 3){
        self.finalRatingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ratingUltimate.png"];
    }
```

Comment: a switch looks more appropriate for this

Comment: You should always copy/paste the *exact* error message and identify what line it's pointing to.

Comment: @JDong Only if `rating` is an integral type.

Comment: @JDong, it seems that rating is not an integer. I can't come up with a good way of rewriting this code using switch in this case.

Comment: Seriously, an operator typo ?
:P

Comment: @FreeNickname good point, missed that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THe problem is the first line. You have `=>` instead of `>=`.